# Find the length of AD to the nearest whole number

Tags: trigonometry

A sketch of a rectangular ground ABCD is given here.

[image]

(i) Based on the information marked on the sketch, find the length of AD to the nearest whole number.

Any Ideas on how to begin?

Comment: So what is the length of $DC$? What is the relationship between $AD$ and $DC$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan 35^{\circ} = {AD\over 40}$$

$$\tan 15^{\circ}= 2 - \sqrt{3}$$

for $\tan 20^{\circ}$ maybe use multiple angle formulae and solve the cubic.

Comment: Is the length 18.952 ?

Comment: @user360471 yes.